# Texturing a human model

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have just started learning Blender. I have been following this course on Udemy.

i - https://www.udemy.com/blender-character-modeling-for-beginners-hd/learn/v4/

I am trying to texture my model but facing some issues in Blender, i am using blender version 2.79.

i have two questions.

first when i seemed the model and unwrap it, it is of the side view, how can i switch it to its front view, and

Second question is when i bake an image on the model it says `no valid selected objects`

[image]

Comment: First please ask only one question at a time. (Edit this question and remove the question about baking.) Now the reason it is unwrapped like that is because you put a seam down the middle of the head.

Comment: how should i seam to get the front view @David

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bake normals with "Selected to active" checked, you have to select an object that contains the details that should be baked and select another object where the details should be baked onto. This object has to be the active object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw seams around areas that you want to unwrap so that you get the most even, and proportional flattened version of that 3D model.

So the best places to put your seams would naturally be along the back of the head, and on any area that naturally creases there. On some people, this will be where the back of the head meets the neck, and you can draw a seam to the ear from there.

Then you should have an unwrap where you get the face flattened with the wrest of the head flowing out from the face.